# NGINX ERROR: upstream prematurely closed connection while reading upstream

Tags: odoo, nginx-reverse-proxy

**Hi everyone**,

I have a question, I spend hours but I can not find the solution, this is my escenario:

**Scenario 1. That's works**

> I have Odoo install on Debian 10, in this server I installed NGINX as
> proxy reverse and all works like a charm.

```
 location / {
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8069;
 }
```

**Scenario 2. That's fails**

> Now I use another Debian 10 with **exactly** the same configuration that
> the previous scenario, only change the IP of upstream.

```
 location / {
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://PUBLIC_IP_FROM_SERVER_OF_SCENARIO_1:8069;
 }
```

> I can use Odoo, navigate, create registers, filter, group, login, all seems normally etc. But if try to get a report (it spend 10 seconds or more to completly) I get the error mentioned "upstream prematurely closed connection ..."

I read many forums and test almost every one suggested configuration on my nginx and nothing works, some suggested solutions I tested was (each solution tested separately):

```
proxy_request_buffering off;
proxy_buffering off;

proxy_busy_buffers_size 2048k;
proxy_temp_file_write_size 2048k;

proxy_buffer_size 1024k;
proxy_buffers 16 1024k;
```

Here is the Nginx config:

```
server {
 listen 443 ssl;

 server_name dbname.domain.com;

 proxy_read_timeout 1440s;
 proxy_connect_timeout 75s;
 proxy_send_timeout 75s;
 client_max_body_size 100M;

 # Add Headers for odoo proxy mode
 proxy_set_header Host $host;
 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
 proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

 # SSL parameters - update with your cert details
 ssl on;
 ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
 ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot

 ssl_session_timeout 30m;
 ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
 ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA';
 ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

 # Redirect requests to odoo backend server
 location /longpolling {
     proxy_pass http://PUBLIC_IP_FROM_SERVER_OF_SCENARIO_1:8072;
 }

 location / {
   proxy_redirect off;
   proxy_pass http://PUBLIC_IP_FROM_SERVER_OF_SCENARIO_1:8069;
 }
 gzip_types text/css text/less text/plain text/xml application/xml application/json 
 application/javascript;
 gzip on;
}
```

**Note**: I use HTTP protocol in testing enviroment, in production I use encrypted VPN, in both enviroments I have the same issue.

Comment: Have you try to `allow` or `open` `port 8072` in the **first** server? Since your **second** server currently trying to access the `8072` port. But if your `nginx` conf in **first** server already use `listen 80`. Then you can just do this instead on the `second` server: `proxy_pass http://PUBLIC_IP_FROM_SERVER_OF_SCENARIO_1;` without the `port` (`8072`). Then you won't need to `open/allow` port `8072` on the **first** server